# How to exclude specific route from middleware in go-chi

Tags: go, routes, middleware, api-design, go-chi

I've been using go-chi for a project and using an auth middleware for routes like this

```
r := chi.NewRouter()
r.Use(authService.AuthMiddleware)

r.Route("/platform", func(r chi.Router) {
    r.Get("/version", RequestPlatformVersion)
})
```

This is applying to all the routes defined after this declaration which are fine.
But now I need to add a route that is used for webhooks. I don't want to apply this middleware to that route since it'll fail. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the middleware within the `/platform` route:

```
r.Route("/platform", func(r chi.Router) {
    r.Use(authService.AuthMiddleware)
    r.Get("/version", RequestPlatformVersion)
})

r.Route("/webhooks", func(r chi.Router) {
    r.Get("/", ...)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For multiple routes that need to use the same middleware, a group is another option:

```
router := chi.NewRouter()

router.Get("/healthcheck", HandleHealthCheck)

router.Group(func(r chi.Router) {
    r.Use(authService.AuthMiddleware)
    r.Use(middleware.Recoverer)    

    r.Get("/route1", HandleRoute1)
    r.Get("/route2", HandleRoute2)
    r.Post("/route3", HandleRoute3)
})
```